# derivative of a special function  in integral form

Tags: tag-removed, special-functions, integration

What is the derivative of $Q_m\left(\frac{\alpha}{x^a},\frac{\beta}{x^b}\right)$ with respect to $x$, i.e,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}Q_m\left(\frac{\alpha}{x^a},\frac{\beta}{x^b}\right),
\quad
\text{  where  }
\alpha,\beta,a,b \in \mathbb{R} 
\text{  and } m\in \mathbb{N} $$

where the $Q_m(.,.)$ is a special function( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function ) , and we have

$$Q_m\left(\frac{\alpha}{x^a},\frac{\beta}{x^b}\right)=
\left(\frac{x^a}{\alpha}\right)^{m-1}
\int^\infty_{\frac{\beta}{x^b}}
\: t^m
\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{\alpha^2}{2x^{2a}}\right)
I_{m-1}\left(\frac{\alpha}{x^a}t\right)
\:\mathrm{d}t$$

where $I_m(.)$ is the modified bessel function of the first kind with order $m $. Please note that the lower limit of the integral is $\displaystyle\frac{\beta}{x^b}$.

Comment: This is purely mechanical -- ask any computer algebra system.  I could post Maple's answer, but the risk of transcription error is large.  You are much better off doing it yourself.

Comment: I just wanted to understand the underlying procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be computed using the 'usual' rules of calculus, along with the formula
$$\frac{d}{d x} \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t,x) dt =
  \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} h(t, x)dt + g'(x) h(g(x), x) -f'(x)h(f(x), x)$$
where $'$ denotes $\frac{d}{dx}$.  If $g(x)=\infty$, you need to take a limit (over a new constant); generally this means that the second term in the formula drops out unless 
$$\lim_{c\to\infty} h(c,x)$$
is unbounded.  Then you have to work harder.